# PSCP copy files from godaddy to my windows machine

Tags: ssh, download, putty, pscp

I want to take backup of my website which is hosted on godaddy.

I used pscp command from my windows dos and try to download whole public_html folder.
my command is :

> > pscp -r user@host:public_html/ d:\sites\;

Files are downloading properly and folders also. But the issue is public_html and other subfolders has two folder like "./" and "../". Due to these two folders my copy is getting failed and I am getting 
"security violation: remote host attempted to write to " a '.' or '..' path!"error.

Hope any one can help for this.
Note : I have only ssh access and have to download it from ssh commands itself.

Comment: I have found the way for this issue. In my case pscp -r -scp user@host:public_html/* D:\sites\    is working fine.

Answer (score 51):

Appending a star to the source should fix it, e.g.

```
pscp -r user@host:public_html/* d:\sites\;
```

Comment: really help me a lot!

Comment: Well done. Don't know why that one was sneaking by me. How is this a security flaw/issue to begin with? Can someone answer me that?

Answer (score 4):

Also you can do same thing by not adding '/' at the end of your source path.
For eg.

```
pscp -r user@host:public_html d:\sites
```

Above command will create public_html directory if not exists at your destination (i.e. d:\sites). 
Simply we can say using above command we can make a as it is clone of `public_html` at `d:\sites`.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing: You need to define the port number over here "-P 22".

```
pscp -r -P 22 user@host:public_html/* D:\sites
```

In my case, it works when I use port number 22 with the above script.