# Transfer files from Linux to Windows using pscp or some other tool

Tags: putty, pscp

**Problem Statement- I want to copy some files from remote machine (linux) to my windows machine. I know I can do it using pscp.**

I tried looking on the internet, I found several articles, but in those articles I was not able to understand and I was having lot of problems in copying the files from Linx box to Windows.

Can anyone provide me step by step method here, so that I can follow that to transfer files. That will be of great help to me.

I am connected to host `cli.vip.host.com` using putty and that is linux with username- `rkost` and password as- `password`. And I want to copy file `a.txt` from linux to windows.

Answer (score 9):

1. Download PSCP from below link

   https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html
2. Run PSCP
3. Got to command prompt
4. Use the below code

   #### Copy single file

   ```
   pscp user@host:remote_path/file_name host_path\file_name

   eg: pscp user1@192.168.1.10:/home/user2/a.txt c:\Desktop\a.txt
   ```

   #### Copy all files in a folder

   ```
   pscp user@host:remote_path/* host_path\ 

   eg: pscp user1@192.168.1.10:/home/user2/* c:\Desktop\test\
   ```

   #### Copy all files & folders in a folder

   ```
   pscp -r user@host:remote_path/ host_path\

   eg: pscp -r user1@192.168.1.10:/home/user2/ c:\Desktop\test\
   ```

Comment: is it possible to tar a directory on linux and send it to windows using pscp?

Comment: In the third case I had to use -r and also /home/user2/* with the asterisk from the second example, otherwise it stopped with the error "security violation"

Comment: After installing POWERSHELL wow64_microsoft-windows-powershell-exe you can open the terminal and execute this command line pscp -r -P (Port as 2222) user@(domain or IP):(path as /var/www/html/WEB) (WINDOWS path as C:\2023\WEB)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem I use all the time netcat. First, you start netcat as server on a machine with an ip IP_address, and afterwards you send the file from the other machine.

```
nc -l -p <port-number> > out_file
```

will start it as server in "listen" state, and will save what you send to it in the file "out_file".(check the man page of your version for more parameters.)

From the other machine you send the file something like this:

```
 < file_to_send nc IP_address
```

(If you want to send an whole directory, you use tar )

I never used it under Windows (because I work as linux engineer). But you can find nc for windows, that work the same as in linux...

Comment: There is a direct way to copy using ssh (you do not neet to install scp). If you look at the command "ssh", you see that its last optional parameters are [user@]hostname [command]. So, instead of executing a remote shell, you can replace the default "bash" by a command, and you can copy so: ssh user@ip cat _file_ >out.  This will copy the remote _file_ into the local file "out". scp is syntactic sugar for this call of ssh.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use pscp, you can do this:

```
pscp -pw password rkost@cli.vip.host.com:/path/to/file c:\path\
```

if this doesn't work try to add enviroment variable:

```
set PATH=C:\path\to\putty\directory;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing POWERSHELL
wow64_microsoft-windows-powershell-exe
you can open the terminal and execute this command line

pscp -r -P Port user@IP:path WINDOWS path

example:
pscp -r -P 2222 user@MyDommain.com:/var/www/html C:\2023\HTML

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure you are connected to your vpn server, (i.e. cli.vip.host.com)
2. use following command from your windows machine

   `pscp -v rkost@remote_ip_addr:/path/to/file/a.txt c:/some_location/`
3. you can see the verbose with -v flag.
4. If you wants to copy directory from remote linux machine to your windows
   just refer my answer in this
   [PSCP copy files from godaddy to my windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136326/pscp-copy-files-from-godaddy-to-my-windows-machine/41675353)