# Transferring file from magnolia cluster to my computer(my harddisk)

Tags: file, cmd, file-transfer, magnolia

I have a windows machine. I use putty software to make a link between my computer and magnolia cluster.

To transfer a file from my computer to magnolia cluster, the command is

`pscp <filename> <magnoliaclusterinfo(youruserid, domain)> <magnolia_cluster location where you like to keep your file>`

I am looking for the reverse process. How could I transfer a file from magnolia cluster to my computer?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer files from Linux to Windows using pscp or some other tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251047/transfer-files-from-linux-to-windows-using-pscp-or-some-other-tool)

Comment: It is not really Magnolia or cluster specific, all you need to do is follow the pscp manual. Your question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251047/transfer-files-from-linux-to-windows-using-pscp-or-some-other-tool